# Multiple INNER JOIN SELECT query not returning data

Tags: sql-server, select, stored-procedures, inner-join

This is a stored procedure to select the full details of a wine.
It takes as a parameter a storage location ID.

This builds properly and is similar in structure to many sp's I have written that work,
however it returns no data. Is there something I am missing?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [sp_retrieveInventory_Full]
(
    @StorageLocationID          [int]
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  [WineName],
            [RackID],
            [RackColumn],
            [RackRow],
            [WineTypeID],
            [WineVarietyID],
            [VintnerName],
            [dbo].[Vintner].[Country],
            [dbo].[Vintner].[StateProvince],
            [dbo].[Vintner].[Region],
            [VendorName],
            [Vintage],
            [PurchaseDate],
            [PurchasePrice],
            [BottleSizeID],
            [ABV],
            [DrinkByDate],
            [FoodType],
            [TastingNotes],
            [RatedBy],
            [RatingScore]
    FROM    [dbo].[StorageLocation] 
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Wine]
        ON  [dbo].[StorageLocation].[WineID] = [dbo].[Wine].[WineID]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Vintner]
        ON  [dbo].[Vintner].[VintnerID] = [dbo].[Wine].[VintnerID]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Vendor]
        ON  [dbo].[Vendor].[VendorID] = [dbo].[Wine].[VendorID]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Pairing]
        ON  [dbo].[Pairing].[PairingID] = [dbo].[Wine].[PairingID]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Rating]
        ON  [dbo].[Rating].[RatingID] = [dbo].[Wine].[RatingID]
    WHERE   [dbo].[StorageLocation].[StorageLocationID] = @storageLocationID
END
GO
```

Comment: Very difficult to advise without seeing sample data and expected results.

Comment: Try to debug it by starting one inner join -> then 2nd -> then 3rd-> till end... Your query seems right but your data is not getting matching.

Answer (score 0):

When a query reruns no result it's because no records exists that satisfy the conditions in it's where clause, or, in case of queries that contains inner joins, at least one of the joins `on` condition returns no records.

The easiest way to figure out what join is messing up your query is to start removing the joins one by one, but to do that, you have to first change the select clause.

What I like to do is this: Start with all the joins except the last one - see if it returns any records:

```
SELECT  1
FROM    [dbo].[StorageLocation] 
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Wine]
    ON  [dbo].[StorageLocation].[WineID] = [dbo].[Wine].[WineID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Vintner]
    ON  [dbo].[Vintner].[VintnerID] = [dbo].[Wine].[VintnerID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Vendor]
    ON  [dbo].[Vendor].[VendorID] = [dbo].[Wine].[VendorID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Pairing]
    ON  [dbo].[Pairing].[PairingID] = [dbo].[Wine].[PairingID]
--        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Rating]
--    ON  [dbo].[Rating].[RatingID] = [dbo].[Wine].[RatingID]
WHERE   [dbo].[StorageLocation].[StorageLocationID] = @storageLocationID
```

If not, comment out the next join and run the query again. Rinse and repeat.

Please note, however, that there might be more than one inner join that prevents the query from returning records.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I commented out the last one and got it working.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)